# How can I determine how many rows a PivotTable generates (Aspose Cells)?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, aspose-cells

I need to conditionally colorize ranges in a PivotTable. I tried to do it this way:

```
private void ColorizeContractItemBlocks(List<string> contractItemDescs)
{
    int FIRST_DESCRIPTION_ROW = 7;
    int DESCRIPTION_COL = 1;
    int ROWS_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTIONS = 4;
    int rowsUsed = pivotTableSheet.Cells.Rows.Count;
    int currentRowBeingExamined = FIRST_DESCRIPTION_ROW;
    // Loop through PivotTable data, colorizing contract items
    while (currentRowBeingExamined < rowsUsed)
    {
        Cell descriptionCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[currentRowBeingExamined, DESCRIPTION_COL];
        String desc = descriptionCell.Value.ToString();
        if (contractItemDescs.Contains(desc))
        {
            // args are firstRow, firstColumn, totalRows, totalColumns
            Range rangeToColorize = pivotTableSheet.Cells.CreateRange(
                currentRowBeingExamined, 0,
                ROWS_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTIONS, _grandTotalsColumnPivotTable + 1);
            Style style = workBook.Styles[workBook.Styles.Add()];
            style.BackgroundColor = CONTRACT_ITEM_COLOR;
            StyleFlag styleFlag = new StyleFlag();
            styleFlag.All = true;
            rangeToColorize.ApplyStyle(style, styleFlag);
        }
        currentRowBeingExamined = currentRowBeingExamined + ROWS_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTIONS;
    }
}
```

...but it doesn't work, because rowsUsed does not take into consideration the rows on the PivotTable on the pivotTableSheet, and so my while loop is never entered.

How can I determine how many rows the PivotTable takes up on the sheet, so that I can loop through the PivotTable?

Or, am I approaching this the wrong way? Is there a different standard way of manipulating the styles/formatting of a PivotTable after it has been generated?

Comment: Wishing you the best of luck with your future endeavors and *The Adventures of Mark Twain*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@B. Clay Shannon, You may consider using any of the following APIs for your requirement. I have added comments to the code for your reference.

```
var book = new Workbook(dir + "sample.xlsx");
var sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
var pivot = sheet.PivotTables[0];

// DataBodyRange returns CellArea that represents range between the header row & insert row
var dataBodyRange = pivot.DataBodyRange;
Console.WriteLine(dataBodyRange);
// TableRange1 returns complete Pivot Table area except page fields
var tableRange1 = pivot.TableRange1;
Console.WriteLine(tableRange1);
// TableRange2 returns complete Pivot Table area including page fields
var tableRange2 = pivot.TableRange2;
Console.WriteLine(tableRange2);
// ColumnRange returns range that represents the column area of the Pivot Table
var columnRange = pivot.ColumnRange;
Console.WriteLine(columnRange);
// RowRange returns range that represents the row area of the Pivot Table
var rowRange = pivot.RowRange;
Console.WriteLine(rowRange);
```

In case you still face any difficulty, please share your sample spreadsheet along with desired results (that you may create manually in Excel application) in a thread at [Aspose.Cells support forum](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx) for thorough investigation.

**Note**: *I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.*

Comment: So which of these would I assign to my rowsUsed int so as to loop through the entire pivotTable - dataBodyRange.EndRow, or...???

Comment: To answer my own subquestion, yes, dataBodyRange.EndRow gives me a good answer (although it includes the column total rows, which I don't need, but I can work around that easily enough).

Comment: @B. Clay Shannon, It is good to know that you are able to workaround the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The `RowRange` property of the pivot table should take you row by row through every element in the table:

```
Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets["Sheet1"];
Excel.PivotTable pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1");
Excel.Range cell;

foreach (Excel.Range row in pt.RowRange)
{
    cell = ws.Cells[row.Row, 5];  // for example, whatever is in column E
    // do your formatting here
}
```

There are other ranges available -- for example, I typically only care about:

```
pt.DataBodyRange
```

Which is every cell within the actual pivot table (whatever is being aggregated).

Comment: Okay, I just noticed you said aspose-cells -- I didn't realize that was a tool; I thought maybe it was a concept.  This is interop.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm quite enamored with Aspose.Cells; I wrote a tip on creating a PivotTable with it here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1156412/Create-a-PivotTable-Using-Aspose-Cells-for-NET-Csh